# Proof of discrete probability monotone convergence

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, random-variables, proof-explanation

I am trying to show that for a sequence of random variables defined on a sample space $\Omega$
$$0\leq X_1(\omega)\leq X_2(\omega \leq ......\leq X_{n}(\omega)...$$

for all $\omega\in\Omega$, with

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)<\infty$$
again for all $\omega\in\Omega$.

Then defining $$E(X)=\sum_{x_n\text{values of}}x_nP(X=x_n)$$ we have commutativity of the limit, $$E(X)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E(X_n)$$

My attempt is below:
That
  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E(x_{n})\leq E(x)$ is clear since
  $x_n\leq x$ for any $n$. Here is a quick proof by contradiction:
  Suppose for the sake of contradiction
  $$
    \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E(x_{n})> E(x)\Rightarrow \exists n\in \mathbb{N}
    \;\text{s.t}\;E(x_n)>E(x)\Rightarrow \exists n\in \mathbb{N}
    \;\text{s.t}\; x_n>x
  $$
  a contradiction of our hypothesis.

Now, let's prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E(x_{n})\geq E(x)$.
    Let $F\subset \Omega$, $|F|=N<\infty$. Then enumerating the elements of
    $F$,
$$
F=\{\omega_1,....,\omega_N\}
$$
 Yielding
$$
  E(\chi_FX)=E[\chi_{\omega_1}X+\chi_{\omega_2}X+.....+\chi_{\omega_N}X]
  =P(\omega_1)X(\omega_1)+.....+P(\omega_N)X(\omega_N)\\
  =P(\omega_1)\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_n(\omega_1)+.....
  +P(\omega_N)\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_n(\omega_N)
  =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E[\chi_{\omega_1}X_n+\chi_{\omega_2}X_n+
  \chi_{\omega_N}X_n]
$$
as the limit of a finite sum of existent limits
      is the sum of the limits
$$
  =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}[E(\chi_{F}X_n)]\leq
  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E(X_n)
  $$
    Since $F$ is strict subset of the sample space.

I am missing the last step, why is it that proving the last inequality for any finite subset proves that $$E[X]\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E[X_n]$$
in general?